# Unable to install ejabberd using Homebrew on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, xmpp, homebrew, ejabberd

[image]I am unable to install ejabberd using Homebrew and am left with this error. I have previously installed ejabberd but uninstalled it due to multiple issues. Any advice?
Mac version Catalina 10.15.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
$ brew update-reset
$ brew install ejabberd
```